# Repair Invalid HTML and XML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a document which has invalid HTML and XML. I need to parse it in such a way that whenever any invalid HTML or XML it encounters it should fix it rather than treating it as a normal string. Till now I have tried this technique

```
Nokogiri::HTML(document)
Nokogiri::XML(document)
```

Both are not working in together.

I also refer this [link](http://www.rngtng.com/2011/02/03/pars-invalid-irregular-html-with-unclosed-tag/) but it didn't help me much. Also, I thought for a hack like to replace invalid HTML and XML with regex but my data is too much big so can't apply that hack

I am calling  Nokogiri::HTML(document) so it handling html very well. But the problem is it is skipping the Xml tag which I don't want. I need those tags to print on the browser

Some tags like

```
</SESSION_CONFIG VERSION=“bgh:3”
<METHODS BASEURL=http://abc.hgd.com /servlet/IAMSERVER/>
<ADD_USER URL=“addUser/>
```

Though I Know some of the tags are not legal but still I need to print on browser

Comment: Can you please add an example of what kind of _invalid_ HTML you want to fix and how it should be fixed?

Comment: Try RECOVER option as shown [here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#parse_options).

Comment: Luis Munoz - It didn't help

Comment: When I tried using Nokogiri::HTML(document) and then It removed the illegal XML tag which I don't want. I want the XML tag to print as it is

Comment: spickermann- I added an example

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure `norecover` so Nokogiri does NOT try to fix the issues:

```
badly_formed = <<-EOXML
  </SESSION_CONFIG VERSION=“bgh:3”
  <METHODS BASEURL=http://abc.hgd.com /servlet/IAMSERVER/>
  <ADD_USER URL=“addUser/>
EOXML

bad_doc  = Nokogiri::HTML(badly_formed) { |config| config.norecover }

puts bad_doc

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>VERSION=“bgh:3”
  <methods baseurl="http://abc.hgd.com"></methods>
  <add_user url="“addUser/">
</add_user></p></body></html>
```